# I want to get string from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

there is a matrix like below

```
[[a1, b, c],
[d2, e, a1],
[c1, dfd, u],
....

]
```

if matched with a specific word, then returns index from matrix.
And find row fixed column.
then I convert Matrix to list.
And I get the result like this `["RESULT DATA"]`.
I just want to get string `RESULT DATA` only without `['']`.

```
r, c = np.where(Matrix == SpecificWord)
find_row = np.where(c == 0) 
result_data = Matrix[find_row,1].tolist()
print(str(result_data ))
print(result_data[0])
```

Comment: What is the output of print(data[0]) ?

Comment: You mean `np.argwhere(Matrix==SpecificWord)`?

Comment: the output of print(data[0]) is ['RESULT DATA']

Comment: I just use np.where not argwhere, I ask that i want extract string only from the list. Because when I write the result_data to a file, then the result_data is printed as ['result data'] not result data.

Comment: Is `Matrix` a `np.matrix` object?  not a regular `ndarray`?  What is `Matrix[k,1].shape`?  What is 'k'?

Comment: yes type of matrix is ndarray. k = find_row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

```
row, col = np.where(Terms == ElemData)
cList = col .tolist()
rLits = row.tolist()
if 0 not in cList:
    return None
else:
    num_col = cList.index(0)
    num_row = rLits[num_col]
    data = Terms[num_row, 1].tolist()
    return data
```